# Linker error in c undefined reference

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined reference to 'delete'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

I assumed this means i'm calling the function incorrectly, but all 3 of these functions are called the same way, and only the delete function gives an error.
 And I can't seem to figure out why

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct node{
    char pln[30];
    char pfn[20];
    int pid;
    float pwt;
    float phgnum;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* back;
}node;

typedef struct head{
    float avghg;
    float avgwt;
    int pntcnt;         
    struct node *first;
    struct node *rear;
}head;



void questions(head *header);
head* create_node(head *header);
head* delete(head *header);

int main(){


    head *header;
    int option;
    do {
        printf("Press 1 to input  Paitients\n");
        printf("Press 2 to Delete a Paitient\n");
        printf("Press 3 to ask Questions:\n");
        printf("Select Option: ");
        scanf("%i", &option);

        if (option == 1) {
            header = create_node(header);
            continue;
        }
        if (option == 2) {
            header = delete(header);
            continue;
        }
        if(option == 3){
            void questions(header);
        }
    } while (option != 4);

    return 0;
}


 head* create_node(head *header){
}

head* delete(head *header){
}

void questions(head *header){
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't get past the compiler; that `void questions(header);` line under `if(option == 3)` is invalid.

Comment: And if I fix that, I don't have any problems linking with any compiler I have.

Comment: Anyway, assuming you _do_ have a linker error in some code that you didn't show us, that error does not mean you're not calling the function correctly, it means that you didn't include a function definition in any of your source files. For example, if you delete those three definitions at the end (and fix your code so it compiles), you will get an error like that from `ld`. Or if you move those three definitions to a second file named `helpers.c`, and just do `cc -o main main.c` instead of `gcc -o main main.c helpers.c`, you will get the same error.

Comment: your definitions `create_node` and `delete` aren't valid since you specify that they have return types, but the implementation doesn't return anything.

Comment: @abarnert In C a function call is considered an implicit declaration if no other declaration is visible, so an incorrect call (a typo in a function name) could easily result in a linker error. Most compilers will warn about it though.

Comment: The code as shown compiles (with important warnings!) and *links* using a recent GCC on Linux. So your issue must arise from be elsewhere. Which OS and which compiler/linker do you use. And *how* do you invoke them?

Comment: @n.m. Sure, but his code as posted has a definition for `delete`, plus an explicit forward declarations for it, so that can't be the problem here. (Well, since the code he posted obviously isn't his real code, given the syntax error, I suppose it's possible that his problem is that the definition actually says `head * deltee(head *header)` or something, but that's at least a wild guess as the other possibilities mentioned here. And I don't see much point in continuing to make wild guesses for an OP who isn't responding to anything anyway. The only mystery is why people keep upvoting this.

Comment: @abarnert indeed the posted code is not the tested code. The syntax error only provokes a warning with some existing compilers though so the posted code can pass compilation in practice.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, I guess it does—icc as well as some versions of gcc. Which looks like a bug in those compilers. Parameters but no types is valid as the start of a K&R-style _definition_ (in which case it would default to int if not specified before the body), but it's not valid as a K&R-style _declaration_ (which can't have parameters at all), or a modern declaration (which requires types). And gcc is clearly parsing it as a declaration, given the warning. And I can't find halfway-between-K&R-and-ANSI declarations as a documented gcc C extension.

Comment: @n.m. But at any rate, that doesn't change the fact that, as posted, there are no linker errors, under any plausible interpretation of the code (or with any actual compiler anyone's tried).

Comment: @abarnert not a compiler bug as long as a diagnostic is issued.